# How can I constrain player movement relative to the level in my AR game using Vuforia and Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am currently developing an AR game using Vuforia, and I have encountered challenges in implementing smooth character movement. Even slight camera movements result in the player being displaced significantly. Is there a method to constrain the player's movement and position relative to the current level? (level/map is a GameObject attached to my image target as the game generates by placing a "map" QR code

I attempted to utilize Unity's built-in gravity functionality, but I concluded that it was not suitable for my requirements. Subsequently, I explored the approach of manually simulating gravity by applying forces to the player object. However, this method applied forces solely based on the player's position, disregarding the positional relationship with the current level attached to the ImageTarget. Consequently, the player and the map ended up in different positions.